# Can "define" (a name of a built-in function) be used as a method name?

Tags: php, methods, constants

Can I use it as a method name in my classes?

It appears to be a function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.misc.php
But I see there listed some language constructs too, like `die` and `exit`.

Comment: There is a difference between a "built-in function" and a "reserved word". Sometimes they coincide. Of course, this could be tested in less time then it took to write this post ..

Comment: yes, I know it works. I was wondering if it's a good idea to use it (good practice bla bla). I know its not for language constructs (like "interface", which also works)

Comment: "define" by itself sounds not descriptive enough. Compare `$x->define(..)` with `$x->defineTemplate(..)`. But that is a stylistic issue and separate from a "will it compile" issue - I gave a -1 because the "will it compile" issue is what can be trivially tested. Test it. Then, if desired, write a better base question using this knowledge.

Comment: FWIW, ["php reserved words"](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php) - note that `die()` and `exit()` are listed here, but `define` is not.

Comment: so its cool to use it then, tx :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**When you can... you can, when you can't... you'll know :)**

See a list of reserved words here http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.php and avoid them. Any good PHP IDE will warn you when you attempt to illegal-name your methods.

**There's another issue.** If you forget **$this->Method()** and you just use **Method()** in your class, it will work as it's defined as a function. This will lead to freak and hard to find bugs.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

class Test {
  function defined() {
    return "Yes you can";
  }
}

$x = new Test();
echo $x->defined();
```

Yes, you can. No, you shouldn't. Using the same name as built-in functions is never a good idea. The word `defined` has an established meaning in PHP, and nobody should have to think harder to figure out how your class is using (or abusing) the word in some specific context.

Comment: I agree - but not because of the name re-use; rather because, at least with the limited context given, the name doesn't seem to convey enough information. (However, consider a special "dynamic variable" type where it will only occasionally be "defined": then it comes down to `defined` vs. `isDefined` or similar.)